# Zend Form Replace DL tags with P tag

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I'm using Zend_Form. I'd like to make a forgot password form that is all on one line like this:

label: [ field ] [ submit button ]

And I'd like it to be all within a single paragraph tag. I'd like the paragraph tag to be *inside* the form tag. So, basically, I'd like to replace Zend_Form's default DL tag with a P tag. I can do it, sort of, but not exactly.

If I use the default, like so:

```
class Application_Form_Forgot {
    public function init() {
        // my fields, no special decorators...
    }
}
```

That produces this HTML:

```
<form {the attributes} ><dl class="zend_form"> {the fields} </dl></form>
```

I'd like this HTML instead:

```
<form {the attributes} ><p> {the fields} </p></form>
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
class Application_Form_Forgot {
    public function init() {
        // my fields...

        $this->setDecorators(
            array(
                'FormElements',
                'Form',
                array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'p')),
            )
        );
    }
}
```

But that produces this HTML:

```
<p><form {the attributes} > {the fields} </form></p>
```

The paragraph tags surround the form. Not exactly what I'd like.

I've also tried:

- Googling and reading a bunch of posts on StackOverflow and elsewhere about how to *remove* the DL tags. Forgive me if I missed the answer somewhere and this is a duplicate.
- Reading the Zend source to figure out a way to do it. I found the DlDt Decorator, but that seems to only apply to the elements, not the form.
- Coming to grips with having the paragraph tag outside the form and moving on with my life.

Can someone please point me in the right direction - if this is even possible?

Thanks,
Phillip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, change what you had to:

```
 $this->setDecorators(
     array(
         'FormElements',
         array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'p'))
         'Form',             
     )
 );
```

If you imagine decorators working by each one rendering 'around' what was there before, with this order it renders the form elements, then around that it puts the paragraph, and then around that it puts the form tag.

Comment: Huzzah! Thank you! And thank you for explaining it. That makes total sense.